# about number of bits required for Fibonacci number

Tags: algorithm

I am reading a algorithms book by S.DasGupta. Following is text snippet from the text regarding number of bits required for nth Fibonacci number.

> It is reasonable to treat addition as
>   a single computer step if small
>   numbers are being added, 32-bit
>   numbers say. But the nth Fibonacci
>   number is about
>   0.694n bits long, and this can far exceed 32 as n grows. Arithmetic
>   operations on arbitrarily large
>   numbers cannot possibly be performed
>   in a single, constant-time step.

My question is for eg, for Fibonacci number F1 = 1, F2 =1, F3=2, and so on. then substituting "n" in above formula i.e., 0.694n for F1 is approximately 1, F2 is approximately 2 bits, but for F3 and so on above formula fails. I think i didn't understand propely what author mean here, can any one please help me in understanding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well,

```
n              3    4     5     6     7     8
0.694n         2.08 2.78  3.47  4.16  4.86  5.55
F(n)           2    3     5     8     13    21
bits           2    2     3     4     4     5
log(F(n))      1    1.58  2.32  3     3.7   4.39
```

Bits required is the base-2 log rounded up, so this is close enough for me.

The value 0.694 comes from the fact that `F(n)` is the closest integer to (φ<sup>n</sup>)/√5. So `log(F(n))` is `n * log(phi) - log(sqrt(5))`, and `log(phi)` is 0.694. As `n` gets bigger, the `log(sqrt(5))` and the rounding rapidly become insignificant.

Comment: if you round it to integers it seems almost perfect

Comment: phi is the golden ratio, `(1 + sqrt(5))/2`, or 1.6180339887. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio. It becomes involved with Fibonacci numbers when you solve their recurrence relation.

Comment: F(n) = (φ^n - φ'^n)/√5.  (φ' = 1- φ) Could you please elaborate on saying `F(n) is the closest integer to (φ^n)/√5` and ignoring the rest part of the formula.

Comment: @Gaurav: (φ'^n)/√5 < 1/2 for n>=0, and we know that the result is exactly an integer, therefore this small fractional part of the formula can be ignored by rounding the large other part.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static int nobFib(int n)  // number of bits Fib(n)  
{
    return n < 6 ? ++n/2 : (int)(0.69424191363061738 * n - 0.1609640474436813);
}
```

Checked it for n from 0 to 500.000, n=500.000.000, n=1.000.000.000
It's based on Binet's formula.
Needed it for: Fibonacci Sequence Binary Plot.
See: http://bigintegers.blogspot.com/2012/09/fibonacci-sequence-binary-plot-edd-peg.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the word `about` is very important, as in `the nth Fibonacci number is about 0.694n bits long`. Second, I think the author means when `n->infinity`. Try some big number and check :)

Answer (score 0):

you cant have say half a bit... the amount of bits must be rounded

so it means

```
number of bits = Math.ceil(Math.max(0.694*n,32));
```

so its rounded up for n>32 and 32 for n<32

for 32bit systems that is

and the number may not be exact

Answer (score 0):

I think he's just using the Fibonacci numbers to illustrate his point that for large numbers (>32 bit) addition cannot be assumed to be constant anymore because it involves more than a singe instruction on the CPU.

Why does the formula fail? For F3=2 the binary representation needs 2bits (3 * 0.694 = 2.082) Take F50=12586269025, which can be represented using 33bits (50 * 0.694 = 35) which is still reasonably close to the true value.

Answer (score 0):

```
N    F(N)      0.694*N
1      0         1       
2      1         1
3      1         1
4      2         2
5      3         2
6      5         3
7      8         4
8     13         4
```

etc.  That's my interpretation.  But then, that means that you have to get to f(47) =  1,836,311,903 before you exceed 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The author is basically describing how large numbers affect the performance of the algorithm.  To be overly simple, a processor can add numbers of the register size very quickly, if the numbers exceed the register size, more low level processor instructions need to be executed.